# Passing the pointer to the local variable v in thread t1 to thread t2

Tags: operating-system

Suppose that a programmer mistakenly creates an automatic (aka local)
variable v in one thread t1 and passes it to another thread t2. Is it possible
for a write by t1 to some variable other than v will change the state of v as
observed by t2?

Please can I get a fully explained answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

Yes, if the new variable is written on the variable that points to the same memory address as v.
When the programmer passed v to t2, he passed v as a reference. So this means that v is still in the Stack of t1. Any change in v which is located in t1 will directly affect the value of v in t2 since they both point to the same memory address